# workflow error - "The workflow is still processing. Refresh the page and try again."

Tags: workflow, error

I have a problem with my workflows, can you help me please with this error?

> "The workflow is still processing. Refresh the page and try again."

I changed my workflow to be very simple, after that, i refreshed services; restarted the server. But this still does not work.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? If 2013, how many Workflow Managers Servers in your farm?

Comment: @Teresa, did you try to terminate the workflow?

Answer (score 4):

After reading your question, i searched on net and get that there are several reason which can trigger this error message. Here is a [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laleh/2014/09/03/sharepoint-2013-workflow-troublehsooting/) about SharePoint 2013 workflow troubleshooting.

The article is giving a walk-through as following:

First checking the workflow manager server. And if the workflow manager server is ok. Then need to check SharePoint server. But first of all you have to install latest version of SharePoint manager in your SharePoint server.

Hope it will help.